# Google App Engine Use Google Apps Non-Primary Domain

Tags: google-app-engine, dns, subdomain, google-apps

I have an application on Google App Engine which I would like to access using my custom domain. I have a new domain that I just registered and I successfully set it up with Google Apps: forwardfour.com.

However, I set this up using as the primary domain for email hosting. I would really like to host this application from a second domain that I just registered and setup as another domain (not a domain alias) within the same Google Apps account. The domain is ffstatic.com.

I've deployed the latest version of my app on Google App Engine and I followed Google's documentation to add a subdomain for ffstatic.com. I created a user whose login is somename@ffstatic.com, and I login as that user to link to that domain.

However, I am only given the option to add a subdomain for my primary domain, forwardfour.com, even though I entered ffstatic.com into the App Engine console to create a subdomain. No where am I given the option to create a subdomain for ffstatic.com, even though it is a verified domain.

Does anyone know why I cannot do this? I've heard that it can be done.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe it is currently possible to add a custom domain mapping on either Primary Domain or Alias.

You'll have to remove ffstatic.com as a secondary domain and re-add it as alias.

**UPDATE**: As Matt pointed out, you now have an alternative that does not even involve Google Apps mapping:

> We have added support for custom domains for App Engine from the
>   Google Developers Console, meaning you can now associate a custom
>   domain without first associating that domain with Google Apps.
>
> To access the feature, visit https://console.developers.google.com/
>   and you will find the option to add a custom domain under App Engine >
>   Settings.
>
> NOTE: Currently we do not support SSL on custom domains created
>   through this method (although we expect to rectify this in a future
>   release). In the meantime, we continue to support SSL (via VIP or SNI)
>   for custom domains that are created through Google Apps, and we
>   continue to provide free HTTPS for all *.appspot.com domains.

https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8517#c5

Comment: Alex is correct - alternate/secondary domains are not currently supported. This is something we intend to fix, in the meantime you may want to start this issue: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=6545

Comment: Thank you, Alex. I had time to check it again, and your solution worked like a charm!

Comment: I have run into the same issue.
However for other reasons the domain cannot be an alias.
Is there another way around this. Or has it been fixed in the last 8 months?

Comment: @user1474424 http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=6545 and http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8517

Comment: Custom domains for Google App Engine are (still) in a very embarrassing state right now.

Comment: These issues are two years old now, and still not fixed. I've already built my app in app-engine just to discover this. We need clear separation of concerns!

Answer (score 1):

This has just been rebuilt with new functionality.

Setting up custom domains is found at https://console.developers.google.com under App Engine -> Settings

You can map multiple domains now, and I think even naked domains.

SSL is not supported at this point though.

Matt